# How to click an option from the dropdown, If the elements are not stored in an array

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When i clicked on inspect element then below is my code:

```
<select _ngcontent-c2="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" id="type" name="Type" required="">
     <option _ngcontent-c2="" disabled="" value="0: null">Type</option>
     <!----><option _ngcontent-c2="" value="1: account">
       account
     </option><option _ngcontent-c2="" value="2: booking">
       booking
     </option>
</select>
```

I want to click on option "1" which is `account`, below is the code which i tried:

```
List <WebElement> Type= driver.findElements(By.id("type"));
Type.get(1).click();
```

But my script is not clicking on the element on which i want to click. Can someone please help me?

Comment: <select _ngcontent-c2="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" id="type" name="Type" required="">
         <option _ngcontent-c2="" disabled="" value="0: null">Type</option>
         <!----><option _ngcontent-c2="" value="1: account">
           account
         </option><option _ngcontent-c2="" value="2: booking">
           booking
         </option>
       </select>

Comment: Show your approach, please… Is it really Java you are using or is it rather JavaScript?

Comment: Java or JavaScript? And I don't see any SQL in the question. Please correct the tags accordingly.

Comment: @deHaar   driver.findElement(By.id("type")).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  List <WebElement> Type= driver.findElements(By.id("type"));
  Type.get(1).click(); This is the way i am trying

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question instead and format the code appropriately.

Comment: <select _ngcontent-c2="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" id="type" name="Type" required="">
         <option _ngcontent-c2="" disabled="" value="0: null">Type</option>
         <!----><option _ngcontent-c2="" value="1: account">
           account
         </option><option _ngcontent-c2="" value="2: booking">
           booking
         </option>
       </select>
The code which i tried:
List <WebElement> Type= driver.findElements(By.id("type"));
  Type.get(1).click();

Some how my total question is now displaying

Comment: @deHaar i am using java only

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("type")).send_keys("option1 name here")

Comment: Please post formatted code in your question (edit it), so everyone reading it may spend less time reading your comments that include code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
List<WebElement> dropDown =   driver.findElements(By.id("type"));

for(WebElement dd : dropDown ){
           if(dd.getText().contains("account")){
                dd.click();
             }
         }
```

I do not know why you have not tried **Select** class which is present in Selenium. For that something like :

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("type")));
select.selectByVisibleText("account");  
//OR
//select .selectByIndex(1);  
//OR  
//select .selectByValue("1");
```

Comment: @ cruisepandey I am a beginner just started automation i don't know about select class

Comment: @NarendraChetan : That is fine , you can try the first code as well as second one. update the result here.

Comment: the second one works for me thank you very much for your timely help

Comment: second one works for me, if you don't mind can u help me with the random selection as i have multiple options please

Comment: Yeah sure. Which element you want to select ?

Comment: want to select any one of the element randomly in that 2 options

Comment: Its a drop down , right ? What do you mean by random here ? All you have are 2 web element. Please elaborate if there is any multi select. Remember multi select differs from drop down.

Comment: can you share the code for multi select ? I think I did not get you on the first sight

Comment: actually i have two options right one is account and other one is booking. So as per the code shared by u every time i need to select only one option either accounting or booking but i want to select one of them randomly meaning when i run my script first time if it is taking the accounting then if  run the script again it has to take booking so ultimately some times it should pick accounting and sometimes booking]

Comment: @NarendraChetan : You can generate random number between 0 and 1 (sometimes 0 or sometimes 1) using this method : public static int randomBetween0OR1() {
  Random random = new Random();
  boolean res=   random.nextBoolean();

  if(res)
   return 1;
  else 
   return 0;
 }

Comment: then call this : select .selectByIndex(randomBetween0OR1());

Comment: @NarendraChetan : If this is helpful for you , you can mark this question as accepted by clicking on check mark which is just under the down vote button and besides my answer.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much for your support @cruisepandey

Comment: No Problem bud ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use select class as given below.

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElements(By.id("type")));
sel.selectByVisibleText("account");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a dropdown it is better to use **Select** class,

Try this code below and import the correct libraries. Library is also mentioned below,

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

Code,

```
String value = "account";
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='type']")));
select.selectByVisibleText(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

directly u can write this code it goes to account

```html
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
driver.findElement(By.id("type")).send_keys("account");
```

Comment: it takes input as account